# JavaScript replace() method best practice

Tags: javascript, express

I'm somewhat new to programming, so looking for some best practice advice. Is there a better way to write the following code, rather than using the replace() method twice?

```
const URL = 'user/profile/:id/result?size=:query';
const URI = URL.replace(':id', '1111').replace(':query', 100); //'user/profile/1111/result?size=100'
```

Comment: This is a perfectly valid implementation

Comment: What happens if the value you replace `:id` with happens to include `:query` then? If you have multiple values you need to replace at the same time, I suggest utilizing the replacer function.

Answer (score 1):

you can use templates by wrapping the string with back ticks (```) and using ${somevalue}

```
var size = 100
var id = 1111
const URL = `user/profile/${id}/result?size=${size}`
```